# Setting XML Attribute for Sandcastle files

Tags: c#, xml, sandcastle

I have a Sandcastle project that handles some documentation for me. I do some of the process in code to build up the files.

Nonetheless I want to create a link that will navigate to another page.

**C# Code**

```
XmlElement link = document.CreateElement("link");
link.SetAttribute("xlink:href", mapGuid.ToString());
```

This will create the element and then set the attribute. The outcome looks like this:

```
<link href="10e3ca23-4b79-42f3-b89c-e6fe924ceef3" xmlns="" />
```

but it should look like this

```
<link xlink:href="10e3ca23-4b79-42f3-b89c-e6fe924ceef3" xmlns="" />
```

The first link does not work but when I add *xlink:* in front of *href* then it works.

My question is how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I normally use XML Linq and get namesapce out of parent like this

```
XElement link = new XElement("link");
            XNamespace ns = link.Name.Namespace;
            link.Add(new XAttribute(ns + "href", "10e3ca23-4b79-42f3-b89c-e6fe924ceef3"));
```

Comment: Why would I need to get the namespace?

Comment: xmlns is the namespace.